# Linear least squares

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

Maybe someone has code of linear least squares?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Example

Answer (score 2):

Linear least squares is provided in Mathematica by the built-in function [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html).

```
pts =
  {{0, 2.38224}, {0.2, 3.26463}, {0.4, 3.73676}, 
   {0.6, 4.12454}, {0.8, 4.72272}, {1, 5.5135}};

lm = LinearModelFit[pts, x, x]
```

[image: lmf]

```
Show[ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

I have found approximation. Is this code right?

```
points = {{0, 2.38224}, {0.2, 3.26463}, {0.4, 3.73676}, {0.6, 
    4.12454}, {0.8, 4.72272}, {1, 5.5135}};

FindFit[points, k x + d, {k, d}, x];
(*Plot[k x+d/.%,{x,0,1},*)

S = Sum[((points[[i, 2]] - k points[[i, 1]] - d))^2, {i, 1, 6}];

D[S, d];
D[S, k];
NSolve[{%% == 0, % == 0}, {k, d}, Reals]
Show[ListPlot[points], Plot[k x + d /. %[[1]], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer looks good, but see my answer for an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Code for linear least squares

```
pts = {{0, 2.38224}, {0.2, 3.26463}, {0.4, 3.73676},
   {0.6, 4.12454}, {0.8, 4.72272}, {1, 5.5135}};

{x, y} = Transpose[pts];
MapIndexed[(X@#2[[1]] = #1) &, x];
MapIndexed[(Y@#2[[1]] = #1) &, y];

n = Length[pts];
ΣX = Sum[X[i], {i, n}];
ΣY = Sum[Y[i], {i, n}];
ΣXY = Sum[X[i] Y[i], {i, n}];
ΣX2 = Sum[X[i]^2, {i, n}];
Clear[a, b];
{{a, b}} = {a, b} /. Solve[{
     (*Normal equations for straight line*)
     ΣY == n a + b ΣX,
     ΣXY == a ΣX + b ΣX2}, {a, b}];

Show[Plot[a + b x, {x, 0, 1}], ListPlot[pts]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate the "anatomy":

$A x=b$

$x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T b$

(omitting various complications: singularity, weighting, etc)

You can do, e.g.

```
pts = {{0, 2.38224}, {0.2, 3.26463}, {0.4, 3.73676}, {0.6, 
    4.12454}, {0.8, 4.72272}, {1, 5.5135}};
{v, b} = Transpose[pts];
a = Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, Length[v]], v}];
ata = Transpose[a].a;
betas = Inverse[ata].Transpose[a].b;
Plot[betas.{1, x}, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> Point[pts], 
 PlotLabel -> (betas.{1, x} == y)]
ss = (b - a.betas).(b - a.betas)
```

[image]

Comment: It is a general solution.